# Is this an appropriate use of bootstrapping? variability in a fleet's fuel economy

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, bootstrap, monte-carlo

I have a data set consisting of the make and models of a diverse fleet of vehicles (e.g. 100 Honda Civics, 200 Ford F150s, 10 Tesla Model 3s). My goal is to estimate the average fuel economy of the fleet, as well as of sub-groupings like compact cars and trucks.

I have no information about model years (or engine) but there's certainly a wide range of model years present. I found a government database that lists the fuel economy by model year/engine. I calculated my estimates by averaging across all engines/years (e.g. my estimate of fuel economy for Honda Civics is the average of the fuel economy of every sort of Civic sold in a given year, then averaged over the last 20 years). I'm not really satisfied with this estimate but that's another story.

I'm considering randomly choosing a model year/engine for each individual car, calculating the fleet emissions, then repeating the process. My goal is to get sense of the variability in my original estimate and report an interval.

Can I use this method to calculate an interval (even a very wide one) that plausibly contains the true fleet economy? Can someone point me to any refinements to this method that I can look into?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could bootstrap this to get a handle on uncertainty -- after all, that's one of the reasons for bootstrapping in the first place.

1. First, ensure that the entire "raw" dataset with $n=460$ cars are lined up in rows of an e.g. spreadsheet, database, etc.  Assume there are 50 classes of cars based on your partitioning scheme, so make a 50 x 500 array $\bf{X}$, where $B=500$ is the number of bootstraps you will perform.
2. Next, "perform a bootstrap" by randomly drawing $n=460$ cars **with replacement**, and for each car ensure you know the make, model, engine size, and anything else you need, to parse the cars using the **same rules** (partitioning characteristics) you already used.  (randomly drawing means select an integer at random between 1 and 460, and with replacement means an integer can be selected multiple times).
3. Calculate the statistics and fuel economy the same way. There will be a different number of Honda's and other models of various model/engine size after each bootstrap.  There can even be no Tesla's selected, but that's ok, so just ensure there is no average if no Tesla's are randomly drawn.  Also, don't create a mean value of zero if there are no Tesla's selected, since the sample size is $n=0$ -- so there can't be an average.  Store the results in column 1 of array $\bf{X}$.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 $B=500$ times, for a total of 500 iterations (bootstraps).
5. Using the data in $\bf{X}$, generate histograms of the calculated statistics in the 50 rows.  The 50 histograms, based on 500 values will reveal the uncertainty around the calculated statistics.  (note: you may not have 500 statistics for e.g. Tesla's or other cars with a small model, since the sample size can be zero during any bootstrap. Just make sure you don't e.g. set an average to zero if no Tesla's are drawn during a bootstrap -- since there won't be an average, it will result in an empty matrix element of $\bf{X}$.